# Bash Jq syntax error using generic object index

Tags: bash, jq

I tried accessing the object using both the generic object index and the shorthand version of it but it appears that the generic object index won't work. Can someone explain to me why?

I have the following json file jsonsample.txt

```sh
{
  "id": "v4cw72hf3",
  "output": {
    "url": "//srv01.cloudconvert.com/download/~ugl5vnrpfO",
    "downloads": 0
  },
}
```

The Jq manual explained the generic syntax

> Generic Object Index: `.[<string>]`
>   You can also look up fields of an object using syntax like `.["foo"]` (`.foo` above is a shorthand version of this, but only for identifier-like strings).

and I tried two ways to access the url field

```sh
jq '["output"].["url"]' jsonsample.txt
jq .output.url jsonsample.txt
```

But the first one doesn't give me the desired results

```sh
#Result for the first line
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.["output"].["url"]            
jq: 1 compile error

shell returned 3

#Results for the second line
"//srv01.cloudconvert.com/download/~ugl5vnrpfO"
```

Comment: it must be `jq '.["output"]["url"]'` or just `jq '.output.url'`

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from the comments and answer, the `["output"]` part just creates an array with item `"output"`. You're missing the `.` to make it an indexing expression, where `.` corresponds to the current input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The input is not quite valid JSON, so the following assumes it has been fixed.
2. The basic form for a pipeline of array and/or object accessors is

   ```
   .[<string-or-integer>] | .[<string-or-integer>] | ...
   ```

   So you'd be safe with `.["output"]|.["url"]`
3. Certain abbreviations are allowed, but different versions of jq differ in the details.  However, it's generally safe to remove an interior `|.`, i.e. one would expect

   `.["output"]["url"]`

   to work, as indeed it does going back at least to jq 1.3.
4. The restricted `.foo.bar` notation is also supported going back at least to jq 1.3.
5. jq 1.4 added support for unrestricted dot-string notation wherein the key name can be any valid JSON string (i.e. with quotation marks), e.g.

   `."foo with space"."bar with space"`